# I need help deciding between iOS Amplify libraries vs AWSMobileClient for Sign In With Apple

Tags: swift, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, apple-sign-in

I currently have an iOS production app using AWSMobileClient and awsconfiguration.json file where I define CredentialsProvider, CognitoUserPool, S3TransferUtility. I want to implement Sign in with Apple into my swift app without loosing any capabilities. I'm having a hard time figuring out what iOS client to use. I believe my Apple and Cognito setup are correct, the tutorials are straight forward for connecting Apple to a userpool as an Identity Provider and enabling it in App Client Settings.

Amplify tutorial for setting up Sign In With Apple: https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/social_signin_web_ui/q/platform/ios#configure-auth-category

But I eventually get to a part where I need to be using the Amplify Pod to call the signInWithWebUI method.

```
Amplify.Auth.signInWithWebUI
```

I skipped over the Amplify add auth cli directions thinking I would just add them manually like I had before. Is this possible to continue using AWSMobileClient or do I need to switch to Amplify and migrate my existing Cognito implementation over?